# Is it possible to SSH OUT from a Nat Gatewy to a public server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-nat-gateway

I can't get this to work with AWS and Nat Gateway.
I am able to SSH in to to the Private instance (Through Bastion), but I am not able to ssh out from a private instance to a public server that is not within my VPC. The Public server is allowing the Public IP of the NAT for port 22 and I am able to access the internet from the Private instance.
I am able to ssh to the public server from another server so I know that it is possible.

However, ssh from the private server behind the NAT to the Public server will not connect and just times out.

I am just not sure if a NAT can handle outbound SSH traffic to the public

Comment: When referencing the 'public server' from the 'private instance', or you using the **Public IP address** of the public server, or the  **private IP address**? It would be preferable to use the private IP address to keep traffic within the VPC. The security group on the public instance should therefore permit the private IP address of the 'private instance' and the connection will go directly from the private instance to the public instance, without passing through the NAT Gateway.

Comment: Seems like some piece of information is missing here. You say that you can SSH into the Private instance but you don't say from where or why that's relevant. You should not be able to SSH from outside AWS into an EC2 instance in a private subnet unless you jump through a publicly reachable bastion host or have VPN connectivity into the VPC.

Comment: Yes NAT Gateways can handle SSH traffic.

Comment: -jarmod, I updated to clarify that I can connect to the private through a bastion server on a public subnet.
@JohnRotenstein, yes this works within private to private, but that is not use case of this setup, I need to the Private to connect to a Public server outside the vpc. Beyond adding the IP of the NAT to the public server, what else is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and I got it working.

The issue I had is since the private servers go through the NAT it is secured by the Network ACL's Inbound Rules even though I am connecting to a server outside the network. So you need to add the Private IP with port 22 access to the Network ACL's Inbound Rules. Or you can add the IP range of your internal subnets which will allow all internal private servers which is useful if your servers are load balanced as they will come and go.

Comment: All AWS users should use the [default NACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#default-network-acl) unless they really know what they're doing, in particular because NACLs are stateless. For more sophisticated AWS users, yes security groups and NACLs offer a helpful defense in depth strategy.

Comment: Agreed. There is rarely a reason for changing the Network ACLs. Always leave them as "Allow All" unless you have a very specific reason (eg creating a DMZ). Instead, use Security Groups to control access to resources.